# Python - pysnmp "NameError: name 'USM_AUTH_HMAC96_SHA' is not defined"

Tags: python, pysnmp

I installed `pysnmp 4.4.12` on Windows with `Python 2.7`, I have been probe the example

https://pysnmp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/hlapi/v3arch/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/snmp-versions.html#snmpv3-auth-sha-privacy-aes128

and I get this error:

```
authProtocol=USM_AUTH_HMAC96_SHA, 
NameError: name 'USM_AUTH_HMAC96_SHA' is not defined
```

the example:

```py
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

iterator = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(),
    UsmUserData('usr-sha-aes', 'authkey1', 'privkey1',
                authProtocol=USM_AUTH_HMAC96_SHA,
                privProtocol=USM_PRIV_CFB128_AES),
    UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
    ContextData(),
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0))
)

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(iterator)

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)

elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                        errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))

else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

Comment: Looks like you missed some imports.

Answer (score 1):

In version 4.4.12 you should use different constants.

```
iterator = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(),
    UsmUserData(self.log, self.auth_pass, self.priv_pass,
                authProtocol= hlapi.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol,
                privProtocol=hlapi.usmAesCfb256Protocol),
    UdpTransportTarget((self.ip, 161)),
    ContextData(),
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0))
)
```